# segue with Dictionary SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, segue

Another question which just should be simple but I am again stumped

I have created a  dictionary from a log in.

It is full of values.  I now want to segue to a  new View controller and take the data with me

So I set up

```
typealias JSONDict = [String:AnyObject]




func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: JSONDict!) {
                if (segue.identifier == "toHome"){

                    var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! OtherViewController
                    svc.toPass2 = parsed!
```

Parsed shows as JSONDict  - all seems well

Over on OtherViewcontroller I  set up to catch it:

```
var toPass2:JSONDict = JSONDict()
```

this builds for me quite happily  and  segues as expected.

But  when I 
 `println("check data: \(toPass2)")`
I get `[:]`

Nothing.
It seems to me I have built it - but nothing is coming.  I could pass individual values - but all I rally want to do is bring the dictionary with me

I also tried the same thing with the  unparsed data string - and this too got me a zero result.

Any help appreciated

Comment: try and replace `var toPass2:JSONDict = JSONDict()` by `var toPass2:JSONDict?`

Comment: Gave that a  go and still no joy.  Your thought is  based on that 
var toPass2:JSONDict = JSONDict()  creates a  new Dictionary rather than accepting the segued data?

Comment: yeah, that was what i thought first. but i think even your solution should have worked cause the segued data is passed after the new dictionary was created... so it overrides it... but you are sure that there **is** something in your dictionary before you pass it?

Comment: Yes I am sure its there -  I can print it to the console, so I know its full.

I thought  my solution would have worked too.   If I  try yours - then I also get the error
if let add2 = self.toPass2["address"] as? String
Cannot  find a  overload for subscript that accepts supplied arguments. 
Yet that if statement works fine in the original view controller.

Comment: this is weird cause when i setup a demo project it works: `typealias JSONDict = [String: AnyObject]`, in prepareforsegue: `let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        detailVC.json = ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value"]`, in detailvc: `var json: JSONDict?` - `println(json)` prints: **Optional(["key1": value1, "key2": value])** which is correct!

Comment: OK so this  would mean my code  is  right  but the placement is wrong?

Comment: Where is the `println` being called - is it in the constructor or `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: in my case i called it in viewdidload!

Comment: the  println  is in the click button action  - which  has gone of and got the data and  parsed it 

If I do it in view did load then I get errors  as the data has not yet been retrieved

Answer (score 0):

in your `OtherViewController` try this:

```
class OtherViewController: UIViewController {
    var toPass2: JSONDict? {
        didSet {
            println(toPass2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean
println(toPass2)

Comment: I get nothing  from trying to print that .

I have my    var toPass2:JSONDict?  outside of view did load  and just in the view controller

Comment: try to setup your `OtherViewController` like above. no viewdidload. no anything. just those 4 lines inside...

Comment: also make sure that you correctly named the segue's identifier in storyboard to "toHome" so that the viewcontroller really gets prepared! - if you do all that it **HAS** to work! :)

Comment: OK I  added that (changed it to be Pass2

Ran it   and got:

setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key usernameLabel.'

Comment: ok, go into your storyboard, select the viewcontroller that caused the error, open the connections inspector (right arrow on the very top right) - there you should see that label. correct or remove that relation and try again!

Comment: Apparently  lengthy discussion is frowned upon- but I do not have enough reputation to move to chat.

When I try what you said I get nothing.   The segue happens but there is nothing to the console.

It seems though that my code was right - but its placement was wrong. 

I called the prepare part in the button clicked action. 



I called the receive part outside of view did load on the other controller.
The controller has been changed as you suggested - I get no output though
The segue works and is named properly

Comment: what do you mean by "called the prepare part"? you use a button to trigger the segue? then the only thing you do is to setup the segue in storyboard by dragging from your button in your sourceviewcontroller to your destinationviewcontroller and give that segue an identifier. you do not need any button clicked action. the segue is triggered automatically. you only need to setup your destinationviewcontroller in prepareforsegue!

Comment: the segue is called in the click button action  the click button signs the user in and obtains their data.  

If the sign in is no good - the user has to retry.
If successful - the user is segued to a new VC - the aim is to take their data with them

So the call to the segue is 
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHome", sender: nil)
And looking at that  sender:nil is where I am wrong  - what should that be?

Comment: would you maybe like to share your project somehow? so i can take a look? :) maybe via dropbox?

Comment: please move the prepareforsegue method out of your signinClick method! and instead of `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperation...` simply call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHome", sender: nil)` without anything around it!